# Adding scene lights to Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to add several extra lights to my Forge Viewer scene but I cannot find any sample on how to achieve this, my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

I am aware of this article: [Add Custom Light for the View and Data API Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/02/add-custom-light-for-the-view-data-api-viewer.html). This is not what I'm looking for, I do not want to create a new light preset, I want to keep the selected light preset and add extra lights around my model to make it more illuminated.

Digging the [viewer3D.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.3.3/viewer3D.js) code I found the following function:

```
  this.initLights = function ()
  {
    this.dir_light1 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_30__["DirectionalLight"](_defaultDirLightColor, _defaultLightIntensity);
    this.dir_light1.position.copy(_lightDirDefault);
    this.highlight_dir_light1 = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_30__["DirectionalLight"](_defaultDirLightColor, _defaultLightIntensity);
    this.highlight_dir_light1.intensity = 1;
    this.highlight_dir_light1.position.copy(_lightDirDefault);

    //Note this color will be overridden by various light presets
    this.amb_light = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_30__["AmbientLight"](_defaultAmbientColor);
    this.highlight_amb_light = new three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_30__["AmbientLight"](_defaultAmbientColor);

    // Set this list only once, so that we're not constantly creating and deleting arrays each frame.
    // See https://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript for why.
    // use this.no_lights empty array if no lights are needed.
    this.lights = [this.dir_light1, this.amb_light];
    this.highlight_lights = [this.highlight_dir_light1, this.highlight_amb_light];

    //We do not add the lights to any scene, because we need to use them
    //in multiple scenes during progressive render.
    //this.scene.add(this.amb_light);

    // Attach the light to the camera, so that the light direction is applied in view-space.
    // Note:
    //
    //  1. For directional lights, the direction where the light comes from is determined by
    //     lightPosition - targetPosition, both in in world-space.
    //  2. The default target of dir lights is the world origin.
    //  3. Transforming the light object only affects the light position, but has no effect on the target.
    //
    // The goal is to rotate the lightDir with the camera, but keep it independent
    // of the camera position. Due to 3. above, we must also attach the light's target object to the camera.
    // Otherwise, the camera position would incorrectly be added to the light direction.
    this.camera.add(this.dir_light1);
    this.camera.add(this.dir_light1.target);
    this.camera.add(this.highlight_dir_light1);
    this.camera.add(this.highlight_dir_light1.target);

    _lightsInitialized = true;
  };
```

So I attempted to create my lights as follow to no success :(

```
const camera = this.viewer.navigation.getCamera()

positions.forEach(pos => {

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFF0000, 1.0)

  light.target.position.copy(target)
  light.position.copy(pos)

  camera.add(light)
  camera.add(light.target)
})

// no effect ...
```

Answer (score 0):

LMV uses custom lights so any extra light sources would need to be added to `viewer.impl.lights` to take effect:

```
const myExtraLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFF0000, 1.0);
viewer.impl.lights.push(myExtraLight)
```

Note in the Viewer’s source code you posted the light sources are also added to the the render’s light array:

```
this.lights = [this.dir_light1, this.amb_light];
```

Comment: This seems to have no effect, I'm adding a bunch of red lights (10) so I would expect to see my model illuminated a bit in red somehow ...

Comment: This actually works, my bad, but the difference is not obvious in my model. I can only notice tiny colored light reflection on the metallic surfaces...