# Autodesk Forge Viewer - adding custom point light into the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to add some point lights into the viewer so that I can achieve the effect of turning on/off light. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3kDp.jpg). I tried PointLight in three.js first . ([effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XETNk.png))

Then I found this question: [Adding scene lights to Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397417/adding-scene-lights-to-forge-viewer) asking about how to add custom directional light into viewer, which is really close to what I'm trying to do. I followed the answer and successfully adding point light into viewer. ([result in viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtKge.png))

But I can't set the light's position. Here's my code snippet for adding point light :

```
function ptLightTest(position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), intensity = 1, distance = 100) {
    let ptLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00, intensity, distance);

    ptLight.position.copy(position);

    viewer.impl.lights.push(ptLight);
    viewer.setLightPreset(0);   //result is more obvios in light preset 'Simple Grey'
}
```

I've checked the ptLight position by console.log. It does have the right value. But still show on (0,0,0) in viewer.

Is it possible for me to set the point light's position in viewer? And I'm wondering if this way suggested? Or maybe there's a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ptLight.setPosition({x:0, y:10, z:10})
```

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment at the moment.

Comment: Thx for your response! But unfortunately,I have tried it and still not work. I tried to set the ptLight position after it added into the scene using `ptLight.position.set(10,0,0)` and I use `console.log(ptLight.position)` to see if the  position had been modified. ptLight position does had been modified to (10,0,0). But still show on (0,0,0) in the viewer.